# Build a language switcher for a one page website?

Tags: localization

I'm building a site with two languages, and I need a language switcher so wherever you enter the website you can switch the language easily. The website is a onepager, so i can't direct to a specific language URL. Instead i'm thinking of adding a segment (/de /fr) to the URL.

I don't know how to display the language fields and language globals.

Comment: Samuel, I removed your question about the visitors' language setting in the browser, as this needs to go in a separate post. But this probaby gets covered by [Brandon's answer to a similar question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2129/125) anyways.

Comment: I think this question is not a dupe, that's why I added an answer. The difference is, that you do not necessarily switch between entries on a one page website. This changes / simplifies the logic.

Comment: Noted, thanks @carlcs! We'll go ahead and reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

The basics for setting up your localized site are nicely written down in the [Localization Guide](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/localization-guide). This walks you through the steps necessary to make your site being available under their subfolders `/de` and `/fr`.

Set up correctly, your templates will always show the field content translated to the currently accessed locale.

If your one-pager template is not connected to an entry (case 4 in the [Routing article](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing)) and you simply save your template files at `templates/de/index.html` and `templates/fr/index.html` (case 6), have a look at the [`include`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) tag, that allows you to maintain one template responsible for all of your locales (e.g. `{% include '../de/index.html' %}`).

The following code is a simplified version of the [example I wrote down here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/882/125), and should do fine for a one-page website:

```
{# Loop through selected site locales #}
{% set locales = ['de', 'fr'] %}
{% for locale in locales %}

    {# Check if `locale` equals the requested page locale #}
    {% if locale == craft.locale %}
        {% set current = true %}
    {% endif %}

    {# Output a link to the hompage and add a class "current" to the current locale's link #}
    <a href="{{ craft.config.siteUrl[locale] }}" class="{{ current ? 'current' }}">{{ craft.i18n.getLocaleById(locale).name }}</a>

{% endfor %}
```